# How to set allow decimal qty to yes for all products magento 2

Tags: magento2, qty

I need to set this configuration to yes for all product is there a way to do it once fo all products ?? any idea please

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

You can do this from Update attributes. [image]

Please check attached picture.

THanks

Comment: but i have always to set it to yes is there a way to make it as default configuration